# Doubt in Lang's proof of solvable extensions forming a distinguished class of extensions

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions, solvable-groups

The context for this question is the same as that is described in [How to see that $M$ is Galois over $k$ in Lang's proof that solvable extensions are a distinguished class? (Prop. VI.7.1, *Algebra*)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3253441/how-to-see-that-m-is-galois-over-k-in-langs-proof-that-solvable-extensions)

However, my doubt is as to why is it that $\sigma K = K$ for all embeddings $\sigma$ of $L$ over $k$? I understand the rest of the proof barring this one step

Answer (score 1):

This is just because $K$ is Galois (in particular, normal) over $k$.  So $K$ is a splitting field of some set of polynomials over $k$, and so its image under any embedding into $L$ will be the extension generated by the roots in $L$ of those polynomials.